# Как отловить параметры запроса в авто-тестах, используя CodeceptJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, test-automation, playwright

Задача крайне проста:

Необходимо совершить действие на странице и проверить, что в конкретном апи-запросе отправляются нужные параметры.

Я использую codeceptjs в связке с фреймворком PlayWright.
Для решения данной задачи есть базовая функция I.waitForRequest, которая проверяет и эндпоинт и тело запроса. Но беда в том, что когда я совершаю действие на странице, запрос отправляется слишком быстро и функция I.waitForRequest не успевает запуститься до срабатывания запроса и потом просто валится с таймаутом в ожидании уже сработавшего запроса.

Выглядят сейчас эти два шага примерно вот так:

```
Then('I click on the update button in the advanced search window', () => {
    I.click(advancedSearch.buttons.update);
});
```

```
Then('I see correct parameters in the API method for banks', () => {
    I.waitForRequest(
      request => 
        request.url() ===
        'https://test-api.test.ru/api/v2/executions?isBank=true',
    );
  });
```

Соответственно нужно проверить, что у параметра isBank значение true. Может быть есть какие-то еще варианты проверки запросов, которые успеют сработать в момент между нажатием кнопки и отправлением запроса?

Comment: Возможно это поможет для решения
https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/996
https://www.checklyhq.com/learn/headless/request-interception/

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете попробовать добавить задержку перед проверкой запроса API. Вы можете использовать I.wait()функцию, чтобы добавить задержку в миллисекундах. Например:

```
Then('I click on the update button in the advanced search window', () => {
    I.click(advancedSearch.buttons.update);
});
Then('I see correct parameters in the API method for banks', () => {
    I.wait(500);
    I.waitForRequest(
      request => 
        request.url() ===
        'https://test-api.test.ru/api/v2/executions?isBank=true',
    );
});
```

В качестве альтернативы вы можете попробовать использовать I.waitForFunctionфункцию ожидания выполнения определенного условия перед проверкой запроса API. Например:

```
Then('I click on the update button in the advanced search window', () => {
    I.click(advancedSearch.buttons.update);
});
Then('I see correct parameters in the API method for banks', () => {
    I.waitForFunction(() => {
      return window.fetch.mock.calls.length > 0;
    });
    I.waitForRequest(
      request => 
        request.url() ===
        'https://test-api.test.ru/api/v2/executions?isBank=true',
    );
});
```